# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que un formulario se envíe si una función llamada anteriormente hace un return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, funcion

Buen día,
tengo la siguiente función:

```html
 edit: function(){
        $('#modal-project-create #botonpartido').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled');
        show_loading();
        var params = $('form[id="editproject"]').serialize(),
            returnurl = $('#modal-project-create input[name="return"]').val(),
             i=-1;
        $("input[name='project_relations[]']").map(function(){
            ++i;
            if(!$(this).val() == '' && !$('input[name="project_relations_type['+i+']"]').is(':checked')) {
                alert('En el vínculo nro ' + (i+1) + ' no seleccionaste el tipo de vinculación');
                return;
            }
        }).get();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: site_url + '/admin/ajax/project-edit.php',
            data: params,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(h){
                if(h.status == 0){
                    $('#modal-project-create #botonpartido').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('disabled');
                    show_error(h.data);
                } else {
                    //show_success('Cambios guardados', true);
                    //$('#modal-project-create').modal('hide');
                    show_loading();
                    alert('Cambios guardados');
                    //history.go(-1);
                    location.href=returnurl + '?edited=true';
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como verán, en el **map()** llamo a una función donde compruebo que si no se seleccionó ningún tipo de vínculo pero sí se ingresó un vínculo, lance un alerta y haga un return;

El alerta funciona correctamente, el problema es que el $.ajax se envía igual ya que se ignora el return; al estar dentro de otra función. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no se envíe la llamada a $.ajax en caso de que en el vínculo no se seleccione el tipo de vinculación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una variable donde se guarde si el envio del formulario es correcto.

Un ejemplo sería establecer la variable al inicio de la función `edit`

```
var isValid = true;
```

Luego solo tendrías que cambiar-la a `false` esta variable en el lugar donde tienes el `return`.

```
if(!$(this).val() == '' && !$('input[name="project_relations_type['+i+']"]').is(':checked')) {
    alert('En el vínculo nro ' + (i+1) + ' no seleccionaste el tipo de vinculación');
    isValid = false;
    return;
}
```

Por último añades un condicional antes de lanzar la petición de ajax.

```
if(isValid) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: site_url + '/admin/ajax/project-edit.php',
    data: params,
    dataType: 'json',
    ...........
  });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Sirvió a la perfección y no entiendo cómo no se me ocurrió antes jaja. Un saludo.